# .htaccess on local to redirect all CDN to local files when i use localhost

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, .htaccess, cdn

i'm developing a web site using bootstrap, jquery and google-fonts By CDN, sometimes i'm on moving and without internet connexion, is it possible to create a .htaccess on my wamp server that can redirect all my CDN links to local images when i'm testing my code by localhost ?

Comment: If your links are external the client will communicate with the external server directly and won't send a request to yours, meaning .htaccess can't change it. What you first have to do it change the hosts file of your system to redirect the external url to localhost and then your server can handle the request. I'm sure a simple re-write rule should do. See mod_rewrite and RewriteRule. Alternatively you can set your page to load different images/scripts if the external ones are not available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
What i want it's to use the same file in local and online without changing anything. 
is it possible to create a .htacces in my wamp server that can redirect 
(http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)
to 
(localhost/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Comment: No. not with .htaccess alone. read my comment above to see why